# Catalog synchronization is too slow, although the sync is getting completed

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am running catalog synchronization with products, category etc. However, I can see too many logs with the following info:

INFO  [SyncWorker<000000S8 2 of 8>] [AbstractItemCopyContext] cannot create item due to pending attributes (..nonmandotory attributes)
INFO  [SyncWorker<000000S8 3 of 8>] [AbstractItemCopyContext] cannot create item due to pending attributes (..nonmandotory attributes)

The sync is successful, but takes a lot of time to complete. The reason for this log is in ItemCreator.java:
if (cannotCreate) {
throw new ItemCopyCreator.MissingInitialAttributes("cannot create item due to pending attributes (values " + this.getCopyContext().valuesToString(initialValues) + ")", this._sourceItem);
}

This flag is true for all mandatory fields as per my understanding, hence would be called for baseproduct attribute also(logged when base product is picked up).
Any inputs on how to avoid this scenario? Can this be the reason for slow sync? Query time looks normal as per jdbc logs